# Should votes on questions have a "time-out" after edits to the question?

Tags: discussion

If someone votes (either up or down), on a question, and the question is subsequently edited, potentially changing its quality, should the votes of users who never (or not within some time limit) revisit that question, after the edit, be discarded?

Comment: No, they should not.

Comment: What good will come outta this? Unfortunately the only thing I can imagine is more time wasted.

Comment: Present a better idea, the downvotes will correct themselves

Comment: Do you not see how a post would be constantly edit-bumped when it's downvoted to trigger this?

Comment: Well, downvotes only mean *I disagree with ya*, and I think you do know that. I'm afraid there's not much doable here. I think the reason for disagreement is obvious though.

Comment: Alongside what @Random said, if votes age away with an edit, someone with 2000 votes has to visit twice the needed questions everyday to make sure his vote remains. This, is just *not* sensible.

Comment: This would be incredibly easy to abuse.  Every single edit would discard the downvotes, no matter how meaningless.

Comment: The abuses go well beyond just this. Let's say I don't like an answer that has 1000 votes. I edit it to zero it out. Nobody is going to come back to recast their vote, and if they do, I'll just edit it again and again. Or I don't like a certain user. So I'll just edit all his posts to zero his rep.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right answer to the implied question of "how can I stop getting downvotes on my questions" depends greatly on the site asked.

On a main site, the resolution is usually fixing the question so it is asking a clear, reasonably scoped, and on-topic question.  There are going to be questions that can't be fixed, but usually most downvoted questions can be improved to a point.  Improvement won't automatically cancel or reverse downvotes, but enough improvement will attract upvotes and hopefully enough to overcome any previous downvotes **over time**.  In  terms of reputation, keep in mind that 5 downvotes can be offset by 2 upvotes (on questions) or 1 upvote (on answers).

But on meta sites, there are simply going to be questions that are impossible to fix.  This is due to the nature of voting on meta.

While the [meta guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) say that downvoting for disagreement is reserved for posts tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), most users apply this rule very broadly and tend to downvote "implied feature questions" - that is posts that are not explicitly tagged [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) but seem to have a semblance of a feature described within the post.  When you post a question about an unpopular topic or about an idea that many disagree with (whether it is a feature request or not), you are going to get downvoted and there is little you can do to salvage the post.  This is why you should do your research and learn the *unique* culture of meta before participating.  Strongly recommended reading: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

If you want to participate on meta, you have to learn that downvotes are simply a fact of life.  You will get them no matter what you post because someone is always going to disagree with you.  In general, they are individual posts that get limited attention (and hence few votes at all), but on average, even the most unassuming post may see a downvote simply because of disagreement.

Comment: Slight caveat to your last sentence: you *can* post without getting downvotes, but that usually seems to be a sign that no one cares enough to push back at all. Which means you probably haven't gotten much accomplished.

Comment: @NathanTuggy that was intended to be broad terms.  Individual posts will get limited attention, but on average, even the most unassuming post may see a downvote simply  because of disagreement

Comment: The other difference with meta is that on a main site, a heavily downvoted question is unlikely to get an upvoted answer, and even if it does the question stands a good chance of being deleted by other users. On meta, a post which is heavily downvoted due to disagreement is much less likely to be deleted (it has value as an example of community opinion), and is likely to get an upvoted answer ("why I disagree with this post"). It only really matters on MSE, as child meta votes don't affect rep.

Answer (score 12):

I very much disagree with this feature request.  It would be an insanely easy process to abuse:

1. Post incredibly low quality question or answer.
2. Voters rightfully downvote content because it is very low quality.
3. After votes stop rolling in, make an insubstantial edit, such as a space.
4. All downvotes are now removed, and the content is still low quality.

This would also apply to high quality content which undergoes tweaks here and there.  The upvotes would also get removed.  Which is also prone to abuse, by editing a competing answer to remove their upvotes.

Implementing this would destroy the very quality metric that SE strives to preserve.

Comment: Couldn't say better myself, +1

Answer (score 1):

> should the votes of users who never (or not within some time limit) revisit that question, after the edit, be discarded?

Nah. This is really arguable as I can see both sides but this is probably going to be useless. I have voted around 1,600 to 1,700 times. I am not going to waste might time looking at around 1,700 posts just to see if they have been edited so I can vote again. Don't even mention those with a whole lot more votes cast than me...

This can really backfire for example, if someone wrote a question that got 100 upvotes then edited it and only 50 people revisit the question. That user just lost 250 rep because people don't revisit the question. Of course, this may help but this is not going to work...

At the time of voting, the voter will "express" his/her opinion on the quality and content of the post by voting. I mean, this is a waste of time and I don't think a lot of people are going to be happy when votes disappear out of nowhere. I mean, votes that are cast by the community are critical to helping others understand the good from the bad.

If this request gets accepted, a lot of chaos will erupt and the posts' quality will slowly decline.